# Solution to system of first order wave PDEs

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

I am solving the following system of equations (the Streeter-Phelps equation models pollution of a river) by the **method of characteristics**.

$$b_t + v b_x = -k_1 b,$$
$$D_t + v D_x = k_1 b - k_2 D,$$
$$b(0,x)=b_0(x)\ge 0, c(0,x)=c_0(x)\ge 0, x\in\mathbb{R}, k_1\ne k_2$$

where $b=b(t,x), c=c(t,x), D = c-c^\infty$, where $c^\infty$ is a constant parameter and $v$ is also constant. I am a bit uncertain if my solution is actually correct, especially for the second equation in the system. I would appreciate if someone could please point out any errors.

My solution:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=v$, so that $x=vt+x_0, x_0=x-vt$, and
$\frac{db}{dt}=-k_1b$, and so
$$b(x,t) = b_0(x) e^{-k_1 t}$$

By the same token, after substituting for $b$ in the second equation, I get

$$D(x,t)=k_1\int\limits b_0(x) e^{-k_1t}dt-k_2 t+const=-b_0(x)e^{-k_1t}-k_2t + h(x) = c(x,t) - c^\infty$$

Also,

$$c(0,x) = -b_0(x) + h(x) = c_0(x),$$

so that $$c(x,t) = -b_0(x)(e^{-k_1t}-1)+c_0(x)-k_2(t)+c^\infty$$

Comment: The solution to the PDE in $b$ is $$b(x,t) = f(x-vt)e^{-k_{1}t}$$ for some arbitrary differentiable function $f$, so you can't just integrate $b$ with respect to $t$ like you did.

Comment: @Mattos Can you please clarify where exactly is the $f(x-vt)$ coming from? Also, where do we use the initial condition for $b$? I thought we could integrate $b_0(x)$, since it's a function of $x$ only, and not $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first equation
$$b_t + v b_x = -k_1 b,$$
$$\frac {dt}{1}=\frac {dx}{v}=\frac {db}{-k_1b}$$
$$\frac {dt}{1}=\frac {dx}{v}  \implies vt_x=c_1$$
$$\frac {dt}{1}=\frac {db}{-k_1b}$$
$$t+c_2=-\frac 1 {k_1}\ln b$$
$$f(c_1)=c_2 \implies f(vt-x)=t+\frac 1 {k_1}\ln b$$
$$b(x,t)=f(vt-x)e^{-k_1t}$$
Now plug it in the second equation and solve it.

As pointedout in the comment by @Mattos your integral is not correct. You need to solve the pde with the same method you used for the first one.

Comment: Can you please clarify where your $f(c_1)=c_2$ is coming from? Also, where do we use the initial condition $b(x,0)=b_0(x)$?

Comment: @sequence we deduce that $b(0,x)=f(x) \implies  f(x-vt)=b_0(x-vt)$ you can plug that in the equation. The problem is your integral that is not correct you have a function of t and x and integrate on t

Comment: So we have that $$b(x,t)=b_0(x-vt)e^{-k_1t}$$

Comment: Can you please clarify where is the $x-vt$ part coming from if we just have $b(x,0)=b_0(x)$? Also why wouldn't it be treated like a constant  in the integral with respect to $t$ if $b_0(x)$ is not a function of $t$? @Isham

Comment: in the last equation in my answer you have the equation that gives $b(x,t)$ put $t=0$ in that equation you get that $b(x,0)=f(x)$ which means that $f(x-vt)=b_0(x-vt)$ @sequence

Comment: True. But why do we need the "x-vt" instead of just "x" in the first place? @Isham

Comment: In the first place it comes from the solution of the partial equation by the method of characteristics @sequence